# after validating data from a registration form, redirect to another page to log in

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

i am new to php and mysql. I am trying to create a user registration form, validate the data, and then redirect to a login page, where they can enter their username and password to sign in. i have written the codes, but for some reason i'm not able to use the header() properly.
Here is my code so far:

```
$userErr= $passErr= $passErrc= $firstErr= $lastErr= $middle= $addErr= $cityErr=      $stateErr=$zipErr= $emailErr= $phoneErr= $passMatchErr="";

$userID= $password= $pass_conf= $firstName= $lastName= $middle= $address= $city= $state= $zip= $email= $phone="";


// Validate the form
// use trim() function to remove unnecessary characters such as extra space, tab, newline,
// use stripslashes(() to remove backslashes 
// use htmlspecialchars() for security
function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // validating the form to see all required fields are entered
    if (empty($_POST["userID"]))
    {
        $userErr = "User ID is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $userID = test_input($_POST["userID"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $passErr = "Password is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["pass_conf"]))
    {
        $passErrc = "Confirm your password";
    }
    else
    {
        $pass_conf = test_input($_POST["pass_conf"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["firstName"]))
    {
        $firstErr = "First Name is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["lastName"]))
    {
        $lastErr = "Last Name is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["middle"]))
    {
        $middle = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $middle= test_input($_POST["middle"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["address"]))
    {
        $addErr = "Address is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["city"]))
    {
        $cityErr = "City is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["state"]))
    {
        $stateErr = "State is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $state = test_input($_POST["state"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["zip"]))
    {
        $zipErr = "Zip is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $zip = test_input($_POST["zip"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["phone"]))
    {
        $phoneErr = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    }
}   
else
{
    if($password != $pass_conf){
        $passMathErr= "Passwords do not match. Please, go back and re-enter the passwords!";
        // die($passMathErr);
    } else{
        // perform sql query to insert the data
        $sql="insert into users values('$userID', '$password', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$middle', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$phone')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql, $connection);
        header("Location:login.html");
    }
}
?>  

<html lang="em">
<head>
    <title> Registration </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1{
            text-align: left;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size: 2em;
            color:#FFFF99;
            word-spacing: 0.3em;
            letter-spacing:0.1em;
            text-decoration:underline;
        }
        body{
            background-color: #421818;
        }
        .txtinput{
            margin-left:150px;
        }
        table{
            font-color:#99FF00;
        }
        .error {
            color: #FF0000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Registration Form </h1><br>
    <form name="reg" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
        <table style="color:#99FF00" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>
            <tr>
                <td>User ID * <td><input type="text" name="userID"/>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $userErr;?></span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password *<td><input type="password" name="password" />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $passErr;?></span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Confirm Password *<td><input type="password" name="pass_conf" />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $passErrc;?></span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name *<td><input type="text" name="firstName" />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $firstErr;?></span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name *<td><input type="text" name="lastName" />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $lastErr;?></span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Middle<td><input type="text" name="middle" />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $middle;?></span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address *<td><input type="text" name="address" />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $addErr;?></span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>City *<td><input type="text" name="city" />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $cityErr;?></span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>State *<td><input type="text" name="state" />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $cityErr;?></span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zip *<td><input type="text" name="zip" />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $zipErr;?></span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email *<td><input type="text" name="email"/> 
                <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone<td><input type="text" name="phone" />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $phone;?></span>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="txtinput">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/>   
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Space after Location: maybe?

Comment: i tried it, and the data is inserted into the database, but it is still not directing to my login page. it keeps displaying the registration file

Comment: <?php
     include("dbConfig.php");
     // define variables and set to empty values
     $userErr= $passErr=....  I have the include statement in the begining, would that stop the header function from working, maybe?

Comment: No.  But any output whatsoever before your header command will.  Check there is no space before or after your <? ?> tags in your include file. (Not even a newline after the closing ?>)

Answer (score 1):

You have to exit from the code segment once the control is transferred to another page. Otherwise the following code will get executed. So use `exit;` after header().

```
header("Location:login.html");
exit;
```

Comment: i added it, but for some reason it is still not working. everything i posted before is saved in a file "reg.php", should I be separating php codes and html codes into separate files? could that be an issue?

Comment: No.  That would not hurt it.  Separating your php from the html just makes your code structure cleaner and more managable.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but looking at the structure of your if/else statements it looks like you would only ever send the header when the request method is NOT POST.  (Ie.  Looks like its in the else section.)  I think its in the wrong place.

It is this else that i just think needs removing.  (Although i am not sure how your validation stops the redirect with your current code)

```
    {$phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);}
    }   
    else
    {
    if($password != $pass_conf){
```

Comment: i've been trying to figure this out for two days now. is there another approach to this issue? maybe I am writing lengthy codes, and make it more complicated than it needs to be. I tried changing the if/else statements, yet still no redirection to the login page

Comment: I might post some suggestions for you tomorrow.  I am not at my computer right now and its hard work from my phone. :P

Comment: of course, not a problem. i really appreciate you taking some time to help me out. i'm new to all this, trying to work my way around php $ sql. just so you know, i have include("dbConfig.php") at the beginning of the file, not sure if that hinders the header() from executing.

Answer (score 1):

try using ob_start(); at the top of the file and ob_end_flush(); at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Are you sure this works or is it a suggestion?  If the latter, it's better as a comment.

Comment: I haven't tested it. In this case we don't want to bother about any white space or new line in the file content because output buffer will ignore all html outputs when header redirection is called.

Comment: i used the exit; right after the header call, and now when i go to the registration page, it does not even show the form, it instantly redirects to the login page. where would i place the ob_start() function based on the above code?  ob_start() in the beginning after the <?php, and ob_end_flush before the ?> <html>

Comment: Now the header redirect is working right. Now what happens is when you try to access the page the request is of type GET so else case of if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") will executed, there $password == $pass_conf so the code block with header redirect works and it instantly redirects to login. The form should comes ideally inside the else case of "if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")"

Answer (score 1):

ok you said your data gets into db normally, yet your header() fails to redirect.
The only way for this to happen is for some characters to be echoed before the header() takes place.

Make sure nothing is printed before your header().
Make sure there is no BOM element at the start of your page.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the else part of main if statement ans the password confirmation part put in main if statement :

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
  some coce
}
//""""
else
{
    if($password != $pass_conf){
        $passMathErr= "Passwords do not match. Please, go back and re-enter the passwords!";
        // die($passMathErr);
    } else{
        $sql="insert into users values('$userID', '$password', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$middle', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$phone')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql, $connection);
        header("Location:login.html");
    }
} //"""
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
  some coce
}
//""""
else
{
    if($password != $pass_conf){
        $passMathErr= "Passwords do not match. Please, go back and re-enter the passwords!";
        // die($passMathErr);
    } else{
        // perform sql query to insert the data
        $sql="insert into users values('$userID', '$password', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$middle', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$phone')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql, $connection);
        header("Location:login.html");
    }
} //"""
        // perform sql query to insert the data
```

remove the above """ part and add it inside main if statement

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this....

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // validating the form to see all required fields are entered
    if (empty($_POST["userID"]))
    {
        $userErr = "User ID is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $userID = test_input($_POST["userID"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $passErr = "Password is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["pass_conf"]))
    {
        $passErrc = "Confirm your password";
    }
    else
    {
        $pass_conf = test_input($_POST["pass_conf"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["firstName"]))
    {
        $firstErr = "First Name is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["lastName"]))
    {
        $lastErr = "Last Name is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["middle"]))
    {
        $middle = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $middle= test_input($_POST["middle"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["address"]))
    {
        $addErr = "Address is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["city"]))
    {
        $cityErr = "City is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["state"]))
    {
        $stateErr = "State is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $state = test_input($_POST["state"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["zip"]))
    {
        $zipErr = "Zip is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $zip = test_input($_POST["zip"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["phone"]))
    {
        $phoneErr = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    }
    if($password != $pass_conf){
        $passMathErr= "Passwords do not match. Please, go back and re-enter the passwords!";
        // die($passMathErr);
    } else{
        // perform sql query to insert the data
        $sql="insert into users values('$userID', '$password', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$middle', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$phone')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql, $connection);
        header("Location: login.html");
    }
}
?>
```

The mistake is - you are executing your redirect condition only if the
***REQUESTED method is NOT EQUAL to POST***.

So the above code executes if the request method is POST & the password entered matches the confirm password, then redirect the user to login page. It would work now!

Answer (score 0):

put your header("Location: login.html"); in if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") rather than else part of this if statement.